# How to find optimal store location considering road availability and road condition using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst, select-by-location, spatial-analysis, location-allocation

Recently, I am struggling with how to find optimal store location considering road availability and road condition using ArcGIS Pro. I have tried the location-allocation function in ArcGIS Pro. But I found that it found optimal store location using **linear distance** instead of considering road availability and road condition as shown below.
[image]

How can I find optimal store location considering road availability and road condition using ArcGIS Pro?

Comment: Not sure if you tried the network analyst capabilities in AGP. https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/ready-to-use/itemdesc-findclosestfacilities.htm
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/ready-to-use/itemdesc-findroutes.htm

Comment: If the solver is using *linear distance*, I'd go back and read the help/tutorials and make sure you've setup location-allocation properly. A Location-allocation analysis layer requires a network dataset. This network dataset allows the solver to determine "Best" by distance, time, etc.